# Wordpress shortcode scrape parameters

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have a shortcode created by a plugin, it looks like that: `[nextpage title="button title" acp_seo_title="new post" acp_seo_description="new description"]`. Now I need to read the `acp_seo_title` and `acp_seo_description` inside the `function.php` file. How's that possible?

Comment: How did you create the shortcode

Comment: can you share me your shortcode function?

Comment: @VidyaL the shortcode comes from a plugin called advanced content pagination, I just added 2 new params to the `vc_map`: `acp_seo_description` and `acp_seo_title`

Comment: @vel the shortcode comes from a plugin called advanced content pagination, I just added 2 new params to the `vc_map`: `acp_seo_description` and `acp_seo_title`